# Simple Javascript not working when pushed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku

I know that there have been some questions regarding Javascript not working in Heroku due to [asset pipeline compilation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869180/heroku-cedar-javascript-not-working) etc ... which is way above my head.

I just wanted to add a simple link (see below) to my simple application built with Middleman which should reload page onclick and in turn trigger shuffle! method:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="window.location.reload()">Click to refresh</a>
```

Is that even possible? It works fine locally, but no longer works when I push to Heroku. Any thoughts/help appreciated thanks.

Here is a link to the actual app on Heroku: http://coastguard-quiz.herokuapp.com/

My index.html.erb code is below:

```
---
title: Coast Guard Quiz
---

<h1>Coast Guard Rank Quiz</h1>

<h3>Guess the enlisted insignia below:</h3>

<%

seaman_recruit = {
    img: "<img src = 'images/USCG_SR.png'>",
    name: "Seaman Recruit",
    en_class: "Seaman",
}

seaman_apprentice = {
    img: "<img src = 'images/USCG_SA.png'>",
    name: "Seaman Apprentice",
    en_class: "Seaman",
}

seaman = {
    img:  "<img src = 'images/USCG_SM.png'>",
    name: "Seaman",
    en_class: "Seaman",
    abbr: "SN",
    title:"Seaman (last name)",
    paygrade: "E3"
}

ranks = [seaman_recruit, seaman_apprentice, seaman, pettyofficer3, pettyofficer2, pettyofficer1]

current_rank = ranks.shuffle!.first

img_now = current_rank[:img]
name_now = current_rank[:name]
class_now = current_rank[:en_class]
abbr_now = current_rank[:abbr]
title_now = current_rank[:title]
paygrade_now = current_rank[:paygrade]

%>

<div id="container" class="shadow">

    <p><%= img_now %></p>
    <div id="hideaway" style="display:none;">
        <p class="bld"><%= name_now %></p>
        <p><%= class_now %></p>
        <p><%= abbr_now %></p>
        <p><%= title_now %></p>
        <p><%= paygrade_now %></p>
        <a href="javascript:;" onClick="document.getElementById('hideaway').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('showme').style.display='block'">Hide Answer</a>
    </div>

    <div id="showme">
    <a class="show" href="javascript:;" onClick="document.getElementById('hideaway').style.display='block'; document.getElementById('showme').style.display='none';">Get answer</a>
    </div>

</div>

<a href="javascript:;" onClick="window.location.reload()">Click to refresh</a>
```

Comment: Please post the source-code of the current page. We need to see the code that gets executed by the browser, not the code sent to the browser.

Comment: onClick="window.location.href=window.location" - should solve your issue

Comment: As a side note, please don't set variables in the view. All the code before the `id="container"` is responsibility of the controller, not the view.

Comment: The link you posted works perfectly for me with Google Chrome.

Comment: it works on MAC OS Safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given how simple is the string, I don't think this is the source of your problem. It's more likely the minification of the assets messed up your JS and there is a JS error somewhere before the code is evaluated causing the JS to not work.

I suggest you to open the page with a JavaScript developer tool (such as [Google Chrome JS console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)) and check if there is any error logged in the console.

---

UPDATE: The link you posted works perfectly for me with Google Chrome.

Comment: @SteAp here are the contents of my index.html.erb file. Thanks everyone who responded so far.

Comment: does this work if it's like this?
<a href="#" onClick="window.location.reload()">Click to refresh</a>

Comment: Looking back it actually was not a Javascript issue ... rather a Middleman issue. My mistake. Thanks all for your comments though!